# Bash/Shell outputs which grep/sed cant get

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep

I found that some lines in some commands are "ungrepable". One good example, if you have a git repository:

```
git ls-remote | grep inexistent-match
```

It returns, anyway, one first line "From git@github.com:[...]" (or something like it).

I don't even know what is it about, so I'm sorry if a thread already exists.

How may I grep/sed these first outputs?

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only grepping `stdout` when some data is going to `stderr`

Try `git ls-remote 2>&1 | grep inexistent-match`

the `2>&1` will redirect `stderr` to `stdout`

Comment: You can do worse than look at http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html#toc3

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ git ls-remote > /dev/null
```

Are the *ungrepable lines* still showing up? Try this:

```
$ git ls-remote 2> /dev/null
```

Did the *ungrepable* lines disappear?

If so, [Oliver Matthews](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18360807/368630) is correct.

Comment: Can't help asking how this makes up for an answer.  *Please don't bother to explain.*

Comment: This will show if what the OP is seeing is actually on STDERR or not. There's always a chance that the program is actually opening another FD and prints out to that. We had this issue where we were trying to grep the output, and found out that the program was printing them to FD4.